# Feynman integration

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have been trying to prove that the value of
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\log\left(\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\right)dx$

is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{12} $ using the Feynman technique and introducing a parameter in the numerator of the logarithmic term (i.e. $\displaystyle 1+\lambda x^2$)

Expressing the logarithmic quotient as the difference of two logarithmic expressions and proceeding in the usual manner, results in two divergent integrals. Back to square one ! Have I made a 'bad' choice of parameter placement or doing something wrongly?

Comment: I know the "Feynman trick" only from the big bang theory. Not sure whether it works for integrals with an unbounded upper limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best choice is to use $\log(\frac{(a+x^2)}{x^2})$ instead of $\log(\frac{(1+ax^2)}{x^2})$. In fact let
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+x^2)}\log(\frac{(a+x^2)}{x^2})dx$$
and then $I(0)=0, I(1)=I$. Note
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(a)&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+x^2)(a+x^2)}dx\\
&=&\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x)(a+x)}dx\\
&=&-\frac12\frac{\ln a}{1-a}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ I=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln a}{1-a}da=\frac{\pi^2}{12}. $$

Comment: Ah !!!! How did I miss that !!!! Not seeing the tree in front of me in the woods ! Lol ! Thank you kindly !

Answer (score 2):

Direct computation is possible. No need here so-called "Feynman's trick".
\begin{align}J&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\log\left(\frac{1+x^2}{x^2}\right)dx\\
&\overset{u=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}}=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log u}{1-u}du=\boxed{\frac{\pi^2}{12}}
\end{align}
NB:
I assume that,
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log u}{1-u}du=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\end{align}